# Unable to connect MacBook from Windows10 which is in the same network

Tags: networking, windows-10, macbook

I am trying to connect MacBook from Windows 10 which is in the same network 
( Home ) by connecting through Cat5 Ethernet Cable.

When I ping the Macbook IP from Windows, I am getting "Destination host Unreachable". When I ping the Windows IP from MacBook, I am getting " Request timeout"

In the MacBook - Remote Login is enabled.

It was connecting and working. I am not sure, what went wrong. All of sudden, I am not able to connect between two computers.

Comment: You stated that you connected them via a Cat5 Ethernet cable. Is it an [Ethernet crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) rather than a straight through cable? Did you have this cable in place with one end plugged into an Ethernet port on the Windows system and the other plugged directly into an Ethernet port on the MacBook when it was working?

Comment: I am not sure, whether it is a crossover or straight. In mac, i connected through USB Ethernet Port. It was working before. I used to connect MacAgent in my Visual Studio 2015 and use Iphone Simulator on Macbook..

Comment: In Windows, cable is plugged in to its Internet cable holder in  the laptop

Comment: I turned off the Firewall Settings in the Windows 10. I am able to connect the MacBook. Issue is resolved for me ..!!!

Comment: @moonpoint All Apple products since the late 1990's have had auto-crossover PHYs (auto MDI-X) on their Ethernet ports. Crossover cables are *sooo* last century. :)

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Firewall Settings in my Windows 10. I am able to connect my Macbook from Windows 10. Issue is resolved.